# Samba 4.8.3-4.el7 install

Tags: centos, centos7, samba, installation, yum

I have a requirement to install a specific version of Samba on a server, specifically 4.8.3-4.el7 so that it matches other servers already deployed.

However "yum --showduplicates list samba" only shows 4.9.1-6.el7 as being available.

Does anyone happen to know how to install the desired version, as I cannot see a repo that I could reference. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check here (from **rpmfind.net**): https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/7.6.1810/x86_64/Packages/samba-4.8.3-4.el7.x86_64.html

Comment: ajgringo619's answer is the best, we do this all the time on our CentOS systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```sh
rpm -Uvh https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/samba-4.8.3-4.el7.x86_64.rpm"
```